# How to replace x to a random number

Tags: python, random

If someone could help me make a minor script I would be more than happy, GGI20-xxxxxxx output should be GGI20-2562626 for example

Comment: Does every x get assigned a random number?

Comment: yes please I am really bad at python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible answer for your problem

```
input_string = 'GGI20-xxxxxxx'

import random
def replace_val(input_str):
    str_list = list(input_str)
    str_list = [str(i).replace('x',str(random.randint(0,9))) for i in str_list]
    return ''.join(str_list)

replace_val(input_string)
```

o/p : 'GGI20-3428855' (it will vary as result will be random)

`

Answer (score 2):

Just change the digits according to number of xxxx's

```
import random

string = 'GGI20-xxxxxxx'

random_number = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)

result = string.replace("xxxxxxx", str(random_number))
print(result)
# OUTPUT
# GGI20-6187815
# GGI20-5790829
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to replace all the x's in a string with a random number:

```
import random

def replaceXs(s):
 result = ''
  for c in s:
    if c == 'x':
      result += str(random.randrange(0, 10))
    else:
      result += c
 return result
```

Comment: Before you downvote this, consider that the input might have 20 `x`'s in it.  This might be the only way which actually scales to an input of arbitrary size +1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `random` library to generate a random integer with the right number of digits?

```
import random

def random_GGI20():
    result = f'GGI20-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}'
    return result

random_GGI20()
random_GGI20()
random_GGI20()
```

*Note: this solution works if it's allowable to reuse numbers. If the* `GGI20-xxxxxxx` *results must be unique, this is more complex.*

Comment: Happy to help. Is this the solution you were going for? Or is it important not to repeat the 7-digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random number using `random()`, convert to a string, and then replace however many `x`'s your input has with an appropriate substring of the digits in the random number string.

```py
inp = "GGI20-xxxxxxx"
output = re.sub(r'\bx+', lambda x: str(random())[2:len(x.group(0)) + 1], inp)
print(output)  # GGI20-966494
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def random_gen():
    return f"GGI20-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}"

print(random_gen())
```

Answer (score 0):

this is much simple to understand

```
import random

#text type=string
text="GGI20-xxxxxxx"
#convert string into list to perform required operation 
text_list=list(text)

#do a loop till we replace all x with randome number
#note here index method return a error if x not found hence we used try except block

while True:
    try:
        #this index('x') method raise an error when all x are replaced
        text_list[text_list.index('x')]=str(random.randint(0,10))
    except:
        #create temporary string s to save output in it
        s=""
        #convert list to string
        s=s.join(text_list)
        break #break is important for finite looping

print("input text :"+text)
#save output result into main text variable
text=s
print("final output :"+text)

print("done")
```